# Webpage loading with wrong content-type after setting up CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare, ghost-blog, content-type

I recently migrated my blog to the Ghost service, I've also setup an alias DNS record with CloudFlare.

While showing the blog to a colleague I discovered one of the posts wasn't loading properly and would instead prompt to be downloaded with an `application/octet-stream` content-type.

I can view all the pages without any issues and I believe we're both on the same network as well.

Has anyone received a wrong content type like `application/octet-stream` using CloudFlare, or know what I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare really wouldn't do anything to modify the content type. Open a support ticket and we can take a look.